# Selenium IDE down arrow key

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck trying to get my selenium testing to simulate a down arrow key press.

Im just using the html format for my tests and am using typeKeys as the command, the target is correctly found, and for the value I am putting in \40 which seems to be converted into \\40 in the UI. When I run the command it ends up appending \40 to the current value of the input.

I'm using the latest version of the selenium ide from the site.

Any pointers?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selenium provides its own methods for this task.

Try using **keyDown()** instead of **typeKeys()**

Comment: No bother, by the way, if the thing you're trying to test is the down button firing some event (I'm speculating, if not just ignore this) you might want to try cutting out the key press stuff and using fireEvent() directly instead.

Comment: Which object provides the keydown?  The driver object doesn't have it.